# Can the message as defined in a message end event be retrieved for an external task?

Tags: camunda

Is it only possible to use this message in a Java Delegate, or is it available to the REST API?

Context: I would like to have an external topic consumer handle a message end event and log the specific message that was returned.

Comment: Cross-posted on https://forum.camunda.org/t/can-the-message-as-defined-in-a-message-end-event-be-retrieved-for-an-external-task/17532 - not sure which one is better?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the Camunda forum, this is not possible:
See https://forum.camunda.org/t/can-the-message-as-defined-in-a-message-end-event-be-retrieved-for-an-external-task/17532/4

Answer (score -1):

Message End events can be processed through JavaDelegates or through external services too (REST), you can implement a connector or a listener at message end event to consume a message